# MVC5 add new folder and new class. Namespace does now show on other pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is mind blowing for me.

1) I start a new MVC5 project
2) I add a new folder named "Extensions"
3) I add a Extensions.CS file inside that folder and give it a namespace Application1.Extensions
4) I go to any other page and try to access that newly created namespace but it never shows nor allows me to compile.

What's wrong with my process??

Comment: Don't assign the same name to the CS file and the namespace

Comment: I tried that and still the namespace doesn't show. I even tried to use the App_Code folder instead and I get the same error.

Comment: the namespace of the .cs file is ProjectName.folder?

Comment: Yes ... "Application1" + "Extensions"

Comment: When you say "try to access that newly created namespace but it never shows nor allows me to compile", are you talking about adding the namespace in the `using` block, or trying to access it with the fully qualified name? Either way, you should post the code that generates this exception.

Comment: Yes, I was using both the Using and the Fully Qualified name. TheLaw gave me the answer. Thanks AV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the, with a right click on the Extensions.cs file then properties if the "Build Action" has the "Compile"

Comment: So for every new class outside the standard MVC folders, we need to tell them that we want it to be compiled? Do we know the main reason for that??

Comment: New classes automatically have their Build Action set to Compile so I find it odd that it has changed for you.

Comment: Yes usually yes, i don't know what happened to Johnny :(

Comment: Maybe someone in his office is messing with him :p

Comment: HaHa ...maybe, I'll set up a notifier event to see if my wife is messing with my C# code :--)